# How to iterate over Numpy array in user defined blocks?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array over which I want to iterate. Now, I know of the nditer() function which loops over the array taking one point at a time. However, I want to iterate over the array taking 'n' points at a time. Here n can range between 100-200. Any reference as to how that is possible?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434287/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-chunks

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution will be reshaping.

```py
for chunk in arr.reshape(-1,n):
   ...
```

Comment: `arr.reshape` can lead to the array being copied. This is because not all multidimensional array layouts can be represented by a lower-dimensional array layout. For example `arr = np.zeros([10,10,10])[1:,1:,1:]`. In your loop, a copy of arr will be made, and modifications to chunk will not be reflected in arr itself. Chunking is often done to save memory, so this is an important limitation.